# Is there a way to force Protractor test results to display in command prompt window instead of within VS Code?

Tags: protractor, visual-studio-code

Currently, I am working on a project which has somehow started showing the test results within VS Code (instead of the separate cmd prompt window). Any way to toggle this within VS Code as part of launch.json or tasks.json? I'm clutching at straws here...

I'm beginning to think this is not configurable...

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered this was part of a recent VS Code update (10.1). According to the docs, "Since the Debug Console does not support programs that need to read input from the console, the external console is still available and you can enable it by setting the attribute `externalConsole` to `true` in your launch configuration."

Add this attribute to your `launch.json`